# How to block the older version of my app from working?

Tags: android

How do I block existing users of my app from accessing my database if they're using an older version of the app? Or are there any alternatives to get them to upgrade to latest build?

Comment: First question is: How are they accessing your database? For example, is the DB is within the App or a remote DB (say a website DB with a remote connection)?

Comment: If you have already took precaution then it is possible by sending some error to the old version of App. Or you can put version checking logic in the new API and updated App so that all call from new App takes different path.

Comment: @Tigger The DB is hosted on aws, and all app APIs are hosted on aws as well.

Comment: @Raviprakash but how do I target the old version users though? They're reluctant to update to the new version or they were users who installed through DIAWI.com and did not get the update alert.

Comment: So the "new version" sends a header of some kind when making the connection. If the header is missing (due to old version of the app), return some information that tells the user to update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the current version of your app, you can simply check the version of the app installed and act accordingly ():

```
int installedVersion;
try {
   installedVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
if (installedVersion < 10 ){ // assuming your production version is 10
   // show a dialog to upgra or do something else, without accessing the database
}else{
   // the user has the latest version installed, access database normally
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your API return an error code if a certain header value is not present. This header value must be set in the upcoming and future versions of the app.

The problem is if your existing app does not handle error codes by displaying the corresponding error message, you can't have your API return error code -1 for example and error message "Please update to the new app". In this case you risk alienating your current users.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using your method to block the users of the older version!

Answer (score 0):

```
int currVer; 
try { currVer = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode; } 
catch (Exception e) {  }
if(currVer<3) { ActivityClass.this.finish(); }
```

This will catch if current Version less than you try and will stop it from working.
Also you can add a Toast feedback

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Version is too older", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```